# Creating a polygon around a linestring with PostGIS

Tags: google-maps, gis, postgis

I am new to PostGIS and need to ask for some help here.
I have a polyline from google maps (representing an itinerary) and need to build a polygon (buffer) around it with a specific distance in meters or kilometers.

For input, I have the list of Latitude/Longitude points and the required buffer distance.

Can anyone help me build the query so that the returned result is the polygon in Latitude/Longitude coordinates, ready to be plotted on the map ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After testing, I found that the polygon buffer produced by postgis is unreliable.  That is to say, if I want a 5 kilometre buffer around a polyline, postgis will return a polygon which is **AT MOST** 5 kilometres, yet at some points less than this.

Abandoning postgis

Comment: That's incorrect. Here's an example where PostGIS is creating a 25 mile buffer around a route: http://gis5.com/pois_along_route/gm_pois_along_route.php

Comment: @Marcelo - can you provide the code of how you achieved this ?  When I did it on a test provider, the buffer was distorted.

Comment: Why would you want the code if you already said that you're abandoning PostGIS? :p ... (and you've already accepted your own answer, which does not solve the issue). That's not how StackOverflow works!

Answer (score 6):

1. Add the first vertex of your line string again at the end to be able
   to create a polygon.
2. Convert line string to polygon
3. Create a buffer around the polygon

```sql
SELECT
    ST_Buffer(ST_Polygon(ST_AddPoint(the_geom, ST_StartPoint(the_geom))),100)
FROM
    mytable
```

1. If you have your buffer in meters/kilometers and your data in latitude/longitude you might want to first transform your polygon into an appropriate projection (I don't know where you are) and then back into latitude/longitude.

```sql
SELECT
    ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_Polygon(ST_AddPoint(the_geom,ST_StartPoint(the_geom)),4326),XXXX),100),4326)
FROM
    mytable
```

I haven't tried the code but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't using PostGIS, but there is a [RouteBoxer utility in the Google Maps API v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/) that does something like what you are asking for.

Another option: the [JSTS library](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts).

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-buffered.html)

Comment: You are quite right, this is not what I am looking for.  I researched using RouteBoxer beforehand and it is not at all suited to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

For buffer in meters on lon/lat geometries you can use `ST_Buffer` on `geography` data type. This approach allows avoid find suitable projection. PostGIS actualy uses UTM zones for this.

For example, `geometry(ST_Buffer(georgaphy(geom), 100))` returns 100 meters buffer polygon for geometry `geom`.

So, for table with columns seq, lon and lat it looks like:

```
SELECT geometry(ST_Buffer(georgaphy(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat))), dist))
FROM sometable
ORDER BY seq
```

Comment: What about this comment at:
http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html
For geography this may not behave as expected if object is sufficiently large that it falls between two UTM zones or crosses the dateline