# How to expand LineString centerline into a rectangular polygon in PostGIS?

Tags: gis, postgis

I have a table containing LineString geometries (SRID=4326). Given that line, I also have a "left" and "right" value in miles for each row. They may not always be equal.

I want to produce a polygon from that LineString that is properly expanded on each side in miles to form a resulting rectangle.

I was trying to adapt this solution here so far without success: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60655/polygon-to-fill-gap

I can generate two parallel lines with ST_OffsetCurve(), but haven't been able to create the polygon so far. Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a minimum bounding rectangle for your linestring geometry. The function in postgis you can use is ST_Envelope. See https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html for some examples. If you have this rectangle, you can expand it with your given left and right values. See function ST_Expand https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Expand.html

**Updated my answer (according to the screenshots):**
You can do the following steps to create your desired geometry in postgis.

```
drop table linetest;
--create table to test
create table linetest (
    id serial not null,
    geom geometry,
    parallel_geom geometry,
    union_lines geometry,
    polygon_geom geometry   
);
--insert sample linestring
insert into linetest (geom) values (
    ST_GeomfromEWKT('SRID=4326; LINESTRING(100 100, 200 200)')
);
--create parallel linestring (query your field dx or dy for the parallel value here)
update linetest set parallel_geom = (
    select ST_OffsetCurve(geom,
    -15, -- here you can parametrize your offset
    'quad_segs=4 join=round')
);
--union the 2 lines to get one geometry as a multilinestring
update linetest set union_lines = (
    select ST_Union(geom, parallel_geom)
);
--create polygon with function convex hull out of the multilinestring
update linetest set polygon_geom = (
    select ST_ConvexHull(union_lines)
);
--check your result
select ST_ASTEXT (polygon_geom) from linetest;
```

I visualized the situation in qgis, see image:
[image: Convex Hull]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's not producing what I'm looking for. ST_Envelope is giving me a box like so: https://ibb.co/bT9y3R

I actually want to make parallel lines from the centerline like this https://ibb.co/hNKy3R and then "close off" the box and get the resulting polygon, but it would be at the same angle as the centerline.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh i understood your problem now, thanks for the screenshots. See my solution in my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Plan is the following:

- go to some coordinate space where scale on X and Y is similar (they're not in EPSG:4326);
- get offset geometry to one direction via ST_OffsetCurve;
- get offset geometry to another direction by passing negative offset to ST_OffsetCurve;
- concatenate two linear geometries using ST_MakeLine(geom1, geom2);
- convert resulting linear geometry to a polygon using ST_Polygonize.

Tricky parts are:

- sharp-angle geometries can disappear after offsetting to the direction of sharp angle;
- ST_MakeLine may fail if your offset line has complex self-intersecting shape;
- offsetting to the miles in degrees space. I'd recommend to ST_Transform your geometry to EPSG:3857, convert miles to meters and use function similar to ST_RealOffsetCurve from lostgis extension, scaling offser meters value by cos(lat) to account for earth curvature.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, you probably need the answer from here [Creating a polygon around a linestring with PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692276/creating-a-polygon-around-a-linestring-with-postgis)
. The key is [ST_Buffer()](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) function which wraps your stuff with a buffer radius. Not quite a rectangle though - it makes an oval around a straight line. This function accepts points, lines, multilines, polygons and multipolygons, and returns any of them wrapped with that buffer radius.

Comment: Please do not post an answer that is simply a link to another Stack Overflow post. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as a duplicate.